# URL Redirect Javascript

Tags: javascript

URL Redirect Javascript?
I have am trying to redirect an entered web address with a http:// and prompt until a http:// is found and if it is found it will direct it to the website that is entered.

Heres my code so far:

```
function enter() {
    var keepGoing = true;
    var email;
    while (keepGoing) {

        keepGoing = false

        email = prompt("Please Enter Website Address");
        // Website Address validation to see if it has http://
        if (email.indexOf('http://') === -1) {
            alert("Not valid Web Address");
            keepGoing = true;
        }

        // if nothing was entered
        else if (email == '') {
            var email = prompt("Please Enter Valid Web Address");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: the `keepGoing` variable is rather unnecessary.

Comment: `email.indexOf('http://') === -1` should be `email.indexOf('http://') !=0`, because you must validate http:// is the first part of website address

Answer (score 3):

use location.href

```
window.location.href = email;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = email;
```

should redirect the user to the URL contained in `email`

Answer (score 0):

You can set [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location):

```
function enter()
{
    var keepGoing = true;
    var email;
    while(keepGoing){

        keepGoing = false

        email = prompt("Please Enter Website Address");
        // Website Address validation to see if it has http://
         if(email.indexOf('http://') != 0)
         {
            alert("Not valid Web Address");
            keepGoing = true;
         }

         //if nothing was entered
         else if(email == '')
         {
            var email = prompt("Please Enter Valid Web Address");
         }

         else
         {
            window.location.href=email;
         }       

    }
 }
```